# SUBLIME with GREP: Search for words, ignoring certain lines

Tags: regex, grep, sublimetext3

I have a long text document that has over 24,000 lines.
I need to search through for 83 different words and remove all instances of these 83 words when the words occur alone on a line (see example below). The Words will be removed. But the search must ignore:

- all lines that only have capital text
- All lines that begin with a `§` symbol (regardless if the rest of the line has capital or lower case letters).

Example

```
§History of TIME
HISTORY OF TIME
of
Future
Past
Of
Many Of
Official
Officer
North of the town
I am one of them
```

If I search for `Of` then in the above only the third and sixth line would be highlighted.

The first line would not be highlighted because it begins with a `§`.

The second line would not be highlighted because it is in all caps.

`Many of`, `North of the town`, and `I am one of them` would not be highlighted, because it is not `Of` on its own.

Is this possible in Sublime? I think searching for all 83 separate words would make the query too complicated. But if I can search for one word at a time (ensuring it skips all lines that are in Caps and all lines that begin with a `§`, then that would be okay).

If this is not possible in Sublime, is there any other method I can use?

Comment: `§` or `$`? ...

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk It is § (I have fixed it)

Comment: What do you mean by `Many of would not be highlighted, because it is not Of on its own.` - do you mean your search has to be case sensitive?

Comment: Or that it has to the only word in the line but in such case why exclude uppercase words etc?

Comment: Anyway, does this work: `grep -i '^of$' FILE`?

Comment: `The lines that are all uppercase` - so you only want to exclude `^OF$` because if you're looking for lines that only have `of` there wouldn't be any other uppercase letters.

Comment: In case of other words besides `of` - do they also have to be the only word in the line?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199792/discussion-on-question-by-big-smile-sublime-with-grep-search-for-words-ignorin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to remove all occurrences of `of` when a line does not start with a `§` or is ALLCAPS and when not part of a `many of`, `north of`, `one of`, etc. phrase.

Use

**Find**: `(^(?:(?:§.*|[^[:alpha:]\n\r]*[[:upper:]]+(?:[^[:alpha:]\n\r]+[[:upper:]]+)*[^[:alpha:]\n\r]*))$|(?i:\b(?:many|north|one)\s+of\b))|(?i:\bof\b)`
**Replace**: `$1`

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a1lOZf/3)

**Details**

- `(^(?:(?:§.*|[^[:alpha:]\n\r]*[[:upper:]]+(?:[^[:alpha:]\n\r]+[[:upper:]]+)*[^[:alpha:]\n\r]*))$|(?i:\b(?:many|north|one)\s+of\b))` - Capturing group 1 (referred to with `$1` placeholder from the replacement pattern):

  - `^` - start of a line
  - `(?:` - a group:

    - `§.*`
    - `|` - or
    - `[^[:alpha:]\n\r]*[[:upper:]]+(?:[^[:alpha:]\n\r]+[[:upper:]]+)*[^[:alpha:]\n\r]*` - 0+ chars other than LF/CR symbols and letters, then 1+ uppercase letters, then 0+ sequences of non-linebreak and non-letter chars followed with 1+ uppercase letters and ending with 0+ sequences of non-linebreak and non-letter chars
    - `)$` - end
  - `|` or

    - `(?i:\b(?:many|north|one)\s+of\b)` - a case insensitive group matching `many`, `north` or `one` followed with 1+ whitespaces and then `of` as whole words
- `|` - or
- `(?i:\bof\b)` - a case insensitive group: `of` as a whole word.

See the SublimeText3 test, mind to select regex mode *and* case sensitive matching:

[image]